# python/beautifulsoup to find all <a href> with specific anchor text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, filtering

I am trying to use beautiful soup to parse html and find all href with a specific anchor tag

```html
<a href="http://example.com">TEXT</a>
<a href="http://example.com/link">TEXT</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page">TEXT</a>
```

all the links I am looking for have the exact same anchor text, in this case TEXT. I am NOT looking for the word TEXT, I want to use the word TEXT to find all the different HREF.

For clarification looking for something similar to using the class to parse for the links

```html
<a href="http://example.com" class="visible">TEXT</a>
<a href="http://example.com/link" class="visible">TEXT</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page" class="visible">TEXT</a>
```

and then using

```py
findAll('a', 'visible')
```

except the HTML I am parsing doesn't have a class but always the same anchor text.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
In [39]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [40]: s = """\
   ....: <a href="http://example.com">TEXT</a>
   ....: <a href="http://example.com/link">TEXT</a>
   ....: <a href="http://example.com/page">TEXT</a>
   ....: <a href="http://dontmatchme.com/page">WRONGTEXT</a>"""

In [41]: soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

In [42]: for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True, text='TEXT'):
   ....:     print link['href']
   ....:
   ....:
http://example.com
http://example.com/link
http://example.com/page
```

Comment: trying to find a quicker way, to me this takes a little longer to process since it finds ALL href, then compares each one to the text to find a match. Preferably I could parse directly for the links required. Something like when the href has a class you can do findAll('a', 'className')

Comment: @cwal Oh, gotcha (my bad - long day :) ). Try the updated version - it builds it into the filter. Does that do what you want? This will load them as a generator as opposed to loading all of them, so I believe this is the fastest you will get (as there needs to be some way up front for BS to check if a link fits your criteria). Happy to help think through another way if this doesn't work.

Comment: this certainly looks like it works! I had tried this, but without the href=true and it didnt seem to work. Unfortunately I dont have the time right now to check if it works for me but I will as soon as possible and post back my results. thank you!

Comment: getting a TypeError: string indices must be integers??

Comment: @cwal Hmm, and I take it that is on the `print link['href']` line?

Comment: @cwal I believe in this code it will return the text node, not the element node. Try changing it to print link.parent['href']

Comment: yeah. ill test out integers after to see if im still able to pull title and href. if i am then its no biggie.

Comment: @cwal If your test doesn't work, can you post a bit more of your code so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: excellent! link.parent['href'] works! thank you for your help! i would suggest editing your answer so i can accept it!

Comment: @cwal No problem! Also, just to clarify, your source HTML is different than the above, correct? I am not able to replicate the behavior with the above sample, but happy to adjust with what worked for you so we can close the loop :)

Comment: `<li><div class="title">Some text</div><!-- <a href="http://example.com">anchor text</a> --><a href="http://example.com/link"title="Link Title">TEXT</a><div class="clear"></div><div class="links"></div></li>`

Comment: this is a snippet of the actual HTML and im looking for the link with the anchor text "TEXT" to me looks the same as above but i could be missing something

Comment: Can you use `re.compile()` on the text parameter?

Comment: @User, yes, you can. You would use: `for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, text=re.compile('TEXT')):`

Answer (score 0):

Since BeautifulSoup 4.4.0, `text=` parameter has been deprecated in favor of `string=`. So to find all anchor tags with a specific text, you can use the following:

```py
[elm['href'] for elm in soup.find_all("a", string='TEXT')]
```

The above check filters tags where the string matches exactly. If you have other conditions such as the anchor text has to start with a specific string, you can also pass regex or a function that filters for that:

```py
# filter anchor tags whose text starts with `TEXT`
import re
[elm['href'] for elm in soup.find_all("a", string=re.compile("^TEXT"))]

# or a plain string check
[elm['href'] for elm in soup.find_all("a", string=lambda x: x.startswith('TEXT'))]
```

Finally, since `.find_all` or `.select` return a ResultSet object which is essentially a Python list, you can just filter its result using an if statement:

```py
[elm['href'] for elm in soup.find_all("a") if elm.string == 'TEXT']
```